# Map function is not working properly after post request

Tags: angular

I'm getting data in this format after making a post call

```
[
  {
    "model": "fraud.alerts",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "alertname": "alert0",
      "recipient": "admin",
      "runid": "run1",
      "user_id": "benz",
      "status": false,
      "comments": "",
      "time": "2020-02-06T05:04:53.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "fraud.alerts",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "alertname": "alert1",
      "recipient": "admin",
      "runid": "run2",
      "user_id": "benz",
      "status": false,
      "comments": "",
      "time": "2020-02-06T05:54:03.032Z"
    }
  }]
```

```
   this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/alertapi/ ', { recipient: 'admin'})
    .pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return data['fields'];
      })
    )
    .subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val.length);

      return val;
    },
    (error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Rather than getting length as 2 i'm getting length as 396.How do i parse it as json and then use map function over here?

Comment: can you check what the `data` inside `map` returns

Comment: Do you want the `fields` data from each object?

Comment: yes.... @Mridul

Comment: it is giving the entire array data as a string @AkhilAravind

Comment: did you parsed the string ?? parse string and then do map, that should work

Comment: @AkhilAravind but doesn't the httpCLient.post method does that itself in the newer version?

Comment: It sounds like your API is returning everything within quotes or returning text/plain as Content-Type

Answer (score 0):

Proabaly want to loop the data and return the field;

```
.pipe(
  map((data) => {
    return data.map( d => d.fields);
  })
)
```

Comment: this is what he actually does

Comment: the data coming to map operator is an array, So you need to loop it through

Comment: I understand it, but what is the difference between `.pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return data['fields'];
      })
    )` this and `map((data) => {
    return data.map( d => d.fields);
  })` this. Both are same

Comment: `data['fields']` return data if only `data` is an object. But in this case it's an array so it won't work

Comment: @AkhilAravind No, they aren't. The first assumes `data` is an object that contains `field`, and the other assumes `data` is an array with objects that contain `field`